# Accessing the Hall Sensor

Tags: android

This may look pretty straight forward, but I have googled, stack overflowed and searched Android Developer guide as well.

How can I access the Hall sensor present in the phone? I know my phone has one and programmatic access is possible (it came with a Flip cover that worked on the Stock ROM). I'm trying to extend that functionality to AEX custom ROM.

I've played around with various sensors present in the Sensor class (android.hardware.Sensor) - but couldn't find the Hall sensor among it.

So my question - Is High level programmatic access to it is possible, or is it something like Kernel-only, or is there any third party API?

Of course, I know I could instead use a Proximity sensor - but accessing Hall sensor should be simple, right? What obvious thing am I missing?

Comment: guess I could answer, in case I'd understand what you mean by Hall?

Comment: @MartinZeitler I think he is referring to a Magnetometer.

Comment: `adb shell dumpsys sensorservice` might provide some clue.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it just a magnetic field that you want to detect? Wouldn't a Magnetometer give the values you need.

Maybe physical sensor does not exist but a composite one does, i.e. something that will allow you to determine values based on a collection of values from other sensors.

In this case other sensors could be the [Position Sensors](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position)

[image] for example you could get a reading on the magnetic field strength and orientation to perhaps get the value you need.

Comment: I could try that, but I was thinking Hall sensor was as physical as a Proximity sensor and it gives values in Boolean, 1 if screen closed, or 0 if not.
I just referred to the BMM150 product sheet on Bosch website (the Magnetic sensor in my phone), and it does mention the sensor works both as a Magnetometer as well as a Hall sensor. So I guess the best way is to infer from the magnetometer values!